# Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class ImageView in Vivo devices

Tags: android, android-layout

Even though I have the image in all different densities I am getting a crash caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class ImageView mostly in VIVO devices.

I tried adding an image in the nodpi density also.

Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class ImageView

```
<ImageView
            style="@style/ActionBarBackImageViewStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back" />


<style name="ActionBarBackImageViewStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:layout_width">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">20dp</item>
</style>
```

Same Crash in Another image where there is no Style

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/drawer_menu"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp"
    android:src="@drawable/menu_button"
    android:tint="@color/actionBarTitle"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
     />
```

Comment: Please share layout code or imageView code.

Comment: Please check I have attached imageView where the crash happening

Comment: Also, share line number 24 in xml file.

Comment: <ImageView in above code is the line number 24

Comment: I think this error in the style file. so please check your style.xml file.

Comment: Can you check style.xml code i have added. I saw it is added in both main and my application may be that is the issue

Comment: I tried using <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView instead of <imageView and app:srcCompat="@drawable/menu_button" instead of  android:src="@drawable/menu_button" but now i am getting 'android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #24: Binary XML file line #24: Error inflating class <unknown>' error what is the problem in this change

Comment: Check your image drawable path.

Comment: Image is there in Drawable path but its saying Error inflating class <unknown>. This also  in Most VIVO devices

Answer (score 1):

Just try to remove the style and do the static width and height like below and check:

```
<ImageView
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:src="@drawable/back"/>
```

This should work for you.

Or change parent style in style tag by

```
parent="Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton"
```

Comment: Another image view I am facing the same crash where I directly given Width and Height I attached code please check

Answer (score 1):

Change **parent** attribute in your style file.

Update your code Check below.

```
<style name="ActionBarBackImageViewStyle" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:layout_width">20dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">20dp</item>
</style>
```

Otherwise, use the static width and height check below code:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="20dp"
    android:layout_height="20dp" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code in your style:

```
<style name="ActionBarBackImageViewStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton">
        <item name="android:layout_width">20dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">20dp</item>
 </style>
```

I hope its help for you.